# pl/sql cursor processing and output

Tags: oracle

> This is the code below (PL/SQL) that I am trying to get to work.  The result is to list all products by name (product_name) and a 'demand status' column showing either 'low demand' or 'high demand' based upon the quantity of products ordered.  (If quantity is > 2 = High)This is the first time working with anonymous blocks.

```
    My results are as follows (with just a snip) and what it should show is followed after that.

My results:   
Product Name            Demand Status
---------------     ---------------------
Intermediate Ski Boot         Low Demand
Product Name            Demand Status
---------------     ---------------------
Pro Ski Pole         Low Demand
Product Name            Demand Status
---------------     ---------------------
Intermediate Ski Boot         Low Demand
Product Name            Demand Status
---------------     --------------------

Correct results: 
Product Name Demand Status
------------ -------------
Beginner's Ski Boot Low Demand
Intermediate Ski Boot High Demand
Pro Ski Boot Low Demand
Beginner's Ski Pole Low Demand

Thank you for your help.  



declare
    demand_status varchar2 (10);
    quantity order_details.quantity%type;

    cursor p_cur is 
    select product_name
    from order_details, product
    where product.product_id = order_details.product_id;

    p_row p_cur%rowtype;

    begin
    open p_cur;
    loop
    fetch p_cur into p_row;
    exit when p_cur%notfound;
    if (quantity > 2 ) then demand_status := 'High Demand';
        else demand_status := 'Low Demand';
        dbms_output.put_line('Product Name'||'            '||'Demand Status');
    dbms_output.put_line('---------------'||'     '||'---------------------');
    dbms_output.put_line(p_row.product_name||'         '||demand_status);
        end if;
        end loop;

        close p_cur;
        end;
```

Comment: Where are you assigning a value to quantity?  This looks like it can be done with one simply query.  Why use pl/sql?  Please show the input data table.

Comment: I am using pl/sql because I was told I had to do so.  The quantity is coming from a table:  see below                                                   1001 10011 2
1001 10015 3
1002 10011 5
1002 10016 2
1003 10019 5
1004 10018 3
1004 10011 1
1004 10019 3
1005 10017 1
1005 10019 1
1005 10021 1
1006 10012 4
1006 10015 2

Comment: I can't get this to paste in from sql developer right.

Comment: Thank you anyway.  I don't know how to paste out of developer and I won't have time to figure this out before it is due early morning.